# Why when I call an arrow function declared globally in other's function definition I get a "is not defined"?

Tags: javascript, scope, arrow-functions

Function 1 and Function 2 both are the same but with a different syntax. The thing is that when I call function 2 (arrow function syntax) in isItAPalindrome function it gives me a "is not defined" error. But when I declared function 2 within isItAPalindrome function it does not give me any error.

Function 1:

```
function reverseStr(str){
    return str.toLowerCase().split('').reverse().join('');
}
```

Function 2:

```
const reverseStr = (str) => str.toLowerCase().split('').reverse().join('');
```

When I call the function 1 it works the way it's supposed to do.

```
 function isItAPalindrome(str) {

//When I call the arrow function here it works.
//const reverseStr = (str) => str.toLowerCase().split('').reverse().join('');

if (str.toLowerCase() == reverseStr(str)) {
    return "It's a palindrome!";
} else {
    return "It's not a palindrome!";
}
}

console.log(isItAPalindrome("sum mus"));
```

Why does this happen with the arrow functions in?

Comment: You're probably seeing hoisting.  Where is the variable declared?

Comment: ... or block scoping

Comment: probable duplicate of [`const functionName = () => {}` vs `function functionName() {}`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/336859/1048572)

Comment: @SLaks they are declared outside of the function isItAPalindrome, in the global scope.

Comment: @Bergi When I run the code I comment one of them, firstly I declared only the arrow function and it gave me that error, so I declared the same function with the normal syntax to see what happens and apparently arrow functions behave differently from normal functions.

Comment: @Yadiel Arrow functions [are different than normal functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34361379/1048572), but it those differences do not matter in the example you made. Please post a snippet with your complete non-working code